# On/Off Switch driving MOSFET from Battery

Tags: power, mosfet, switches

I'm designing a circuit using a small On/Off switch that can't handle much current. It's going to be driven from a battery that'll be able to output a solid chunk of current and don't want to fry the switch by putting it directly inline. Therefore, I'm planning on using a MOSFET which the switch merely acting as a gate.

Is there any reason the circuit below will not end up working? [*Please ignore part compatibility and ratings, since this circuit is just illustrative*].

[image: Basic MOSFET circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few alteration to the circuit could be done. Somethings like this.

NOTE:

- Putting n-channel MOSFET near to ground is recommended.
- LED is a diode basically, whose voltage drop depends on the color(red:1.2V, green and blue: 3.3V), so a resistor in series has to be provided for LED not to get damaged.
- If you are using 2-3mm LED(those small through hole LED), mostly you need 1-5mA of current based on brightness required. You can calculate something like this. Values of resistor should be calculated(They are for representation purpose only). R1 = (Vcc-Vled)/0.003

[image: schematic]

- To limit the in-rush current on MOSFET Gate, we need a resistor R3.
- To discharge the MOSFET Gate Cap, we need a R2

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I knew I was missing resistors somewhere in the switch path... Those make sense. As for putting it close to ground, if I have a complex load [not just an LED], should I just route all the grounds of that load through the FET and then terminate to ground?

Comment: That could be possible. Just make sure, if you are sensing some parameter of the load like voltage, those have to be properly referenced.

Comment: Thanks @DivB! That makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. Your circuit shows an N channel MOSFET, so you probably want to have it as a low-side switch, instead of high side one--like you currently show.
2. You need a series resistor with that LED to limit the current flowing through it.
3. The switch is OK, but you may want to add a pull down resistor from gate to GND to make sure the NMOS is OFF when the switch is not engaged.